# How to ensure figures fill the page in R Markdown and Beamer?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I am generating Beamer presentations using RStudio through an R Markdown document. Some of my slides have plots on them. I need to scale these plots in such a way they will automatically fill the page. For example, on plain latex code, I would something along the lines of:

```
\begin{frame}{Bla bla bla}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{test.png}
\end{frame}
```

That ensures that the figure will be automatically rescaled to fit the page. Is there a way to do this with code on R Markdown?

I can always set the actual size of the figures manually but then it is a mess if I need to go from 16:10 to 16:9 slides, for example. Is there some chunk option I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\includegraphics{...}` directly in your rmarkdown document:

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation
---


\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{example-image}
```